# Crop image in shape of external clipping mask - fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://thecrimsonsolutions.com/shopifyobjects.com/uploads/1533709331G4Play.png', function(img){
  img1 = img;
  fabric.Image.fromURL('https://thecrimsonsolutions.com/shopifyobjects.com//uploads/1535008793DfCfhT5-pc-wallpapers-hd.jpg', function(img){
    img1.scaleToWidth(canvas.getWidth());
    img2 = img;
    img2.scaleToHeight(300);
    img2.left = 50;
    img2.top = 50;
    img2.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
    canvas.add(img1);
    canvas.add(img2);
  });
});

  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
      width: $("#c").width(),
      height: $("#c").height()
  });



  var background;
  fabric.Image.fromURL('https://thecrimsonsolutions.com/shopifyobjects.com/uploads/1533709331G4Play.png', function (objects, options) {
      background = objects;
      background.set({
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          scaleY: canvas.height / background.width,
          scaleX: canvas.width / background.width,
          selectable: false
      });
      
      canvas.add(background);
      canvas.renderAll();
  });
```

```css
#c {

    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border:2px solid;
   /*  background-image: url("https://thecrimsonsolutions.com/shopifyobjects.com/uploads/1534747034Moto%20X%20PLAY.jpg");*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

In my project, I need to do the custom mobile case, mug, t-shirt cropping

The idea is that user uploads an image he wants to use for his personalized product. For example, he wants a t-shirt with some cool designed quote on it. He should be able to move, resize and rotate the image he chose. When he is satisfied with the position of the image on the t-shirt and press ok, the design should be cropped inside that t-shirt template. So what I need is:

1. Make canvas appear in shape of the product template, maybe clipping mask or something.
2. Display uploaded image over that with options to move, resize and rotate. It is desirable to show image end edges over that template, maybe even the whole picture but with different opacity outside the template.
3. On the click button to crop the image inside the template.

I found about fabric.js a few days ago so I am a total beginner in this and I would appreciate any help with this.

I have attached the code what I have tried.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The full content of your question must be in your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to create one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: @rory I have corrected and edited as per your suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below code might be helpful.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  width: $("#c").width(),
  height: $("#c").height()
});

var imageUrl = 'https://thecrimsonsolutions.com/shopifyobjects.com//uploads/1535008793DfCfhT5-pc-wallpapers-hd.jpg';
var overLayImage = 'https://thecrimsonsolutions.com/shopifyobjects.com/uploads/1533709331G4Play.png';

/* Add your mobile image as overlay to the canvas */
canvas.setOverlayImage(overLayImage, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

/* Add your user image */
fabric.Image.fromURL(imageUrl, function(img){
  img.scaleToWidth(canvas.getWidth());
  canvas.add(img);
});
```

```css
#c {
  height:400px;
  width:460px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border:2px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Have just added the mobile image as an overlay to the canvas and the user uploaded image as a drag/resizable one.

You can also view the code at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kukhapprabu/pen/wEzgjO).